# Nivo line chart custom mesh layer

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-hooks, nivo-react

I have nivo line chart with gaps like this:
[image: nivo line chart with data gaps]
Gaps are covered by passing `y/value: null` in november and december in data series

Tooltip displays only on data points and this is correct, but I want add tooltip at November and December with explanation why there is no data.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add custom layer 'mesh' which is responsible for displaying tooltips on line chart.

1. You have to declare custom layers in <ResponsiveLine component:

   ```
     layers={[
         'grid',
         'markers',
         'axes',
         'areas',
         'crosshair',
         'lines',
         'slices',
         'points',
         CustomMesh,
         'legends',
       ]}
   ```
2. Create CustomMesh component:

   ```
   const CustomMesh = (layerData: any) => {
   const { showTooltipAt, hideTooltip } = useTooltip();

   const handleMouseEnter = (point: any) => {
     showTooltipAt(
       layerData.tooltip({ point }),
       [point.x + layerData.margin.left, point.y + layerData.margin.top],
       'top'
     );
   };
   const handleMouseMove = (point: any) => {
     showTooltipAt(
       layerData.tooltip({ point }),
       [point.x + layerData.margin.left, point.y + layerData.margin.top],
       'top'
     );
   };
   const handleMouseLeave = (point: any) => {
     hideTooltip();
   };
   const nullValuePoints = layerData.series.reduce((acc: any[], cur: any) => {
       cur.data.forEach(({ data, position }: any) => {
     if (data.y === null) {
       const point = {
         x: position.x,
         y: 100, //whatever you want
         data: {
           x: data.x,
         },
       };
       acc.push(point);
     }
   });
       return acc;
     }, []);
   return (
     <Mesh
       nodes={[...layerData.points, ...nullValuePoints]}
       width={layerData.width}
       height={layerData.height}
       onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
       onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
       onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
       debug={layerData.debugMesh}
     />
   );
   };
   ```

When `nullValuePoints` are my custom points with no data

3. Import required packages:

```
import { Mesh } from '@nivo/voronoi';
import { useTooltip } from '@nivo/tooltip';
```

result:
[image: nivo line chart with custom mesh layer]